# What shall i do if scroll don't work when linear layout gravity="bottom"?

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I make the chat display by dynamically adding message elements to the linearlayout. I ran into a problem. It is logical that when entering, lifting the keyboard scroll should not fall below and the keyboard should not close the message. To do this, I used the linearlayout property gravity = bottom, but now scrolling doesn't work. Please tell us how to make the scroll work not from the top down, but from the bottom up

```
<ScrollView
       android:id="@+id/messscroll"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:direction="bottom_to_top"

       android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2">

       <LinearLayout
           android:id="@+id/messagebox"

           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"

           android:layout_gravity="bottom"
           android:baselineAligned="false"
           android:adjustViewBounds="false"
           android:clickable="true"
           android:divider="@drawable/separator"
           android:dividerPadding="3dp"
           android:focusable="false"
           android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:paddingBottom="1px"
           android:showDividers="middle">


       </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you post screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to scroll view for reverse scrolling layout use  app:stackFromEnd="true"
        app:reverseLayout="true" properties of RecycleView to show chat bottom to top(new to old)

Comment: Do you mean that I should shove a scrollview with a normal gravity linearlayout into a RecycleView and apply the properties you described?

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird workaround that worked for me. Try adding android:elevation = "4dp" to the linear layout. And this isn't how you are supposed to use android gravity.

Comment: I need to add elements in linearlayout, but the scroll does not go up. The solution I found is to use gravity. If you have a better option, I would ask you to tell me. And elevation 4 for linearlayout doesn't work for me. But thank you all the same!